# Вставить значение в форму, которая в iframe

Tags: jquery

Как перенести данные в *input*, который находится в *iframe*?

Вот рабочий код, который забирает нужный текст и вставляет его в *input*:

```
$('td a').on('click', function (){
    var value = $('#js_th-1').text();
    $('#field').val($('#field').val() + value);
});
```

Он работает на странице, но я не знаю как перенести полученную информацию в *iframe*, где расположена форма.

Answer (score 2):

Смотря как заполнен iframe. Если через src, то так просто не получится. Особенно если с разных доменов. 
Срабатывает простая защита браузера. Тут вам поможет postMessage если есть возможность в iframe добавить скрипт. Там прилично кода с обеих сторон. В особенности для разных доменов. Для одного домена попроще, но тоже не сказать чтобы сильно.

Если же iframe заполнен динамически, то тут все проще. 
Что-то типа этого:

```
$('#input_id', iframe.contentWindow.document).val('bla');
```

Должно с работать по идеи. К сожалению протестить не могу, пишу с телефона.